# What does this code segment in python mean?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand what is going on here, specifically how curids is getting set:

```
 for idx in xrange(0, int(math.ceil(float(len(mids))/chunk))):
            curids = mids[int(idx*chunk):int((idx*chunk)+chunk)]
```

I'm not sure what the syntax for `mids[int(idx*chunk):int((idx*chunk)+chunk)]` is trying to do.

Comment: It's an [array slice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It extracts blocks of `mids` into `curids`, where each block consists of `chunk` elements.

If you change the loop to print out the values of `int(idx*chunk)` and `int((idx*chunk)+chunk)]`, you'll see that for yourself.

For example, if `len(mids)==50` and `chunk==12`, the indices that would get printed are:

```
0 12
12 24
24 36
36 48
48 60
```

These are the starting and ending indices of each slice of `mids` (the start index is inclusive and the end index is not).

Note that the last value is allowed to go above `len(mids)`, but that's not a problem given how [Python slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation) works (it'll just slice to the end of `mids`).

Answer (score 0):

It extracts chunk number of elements from mids starting at idx*chunk and places them into curids.

Answer (score 0):

The code `mids[int(idx*chunk):int((idx*chunk)+chunk)]` is getting a subset of the list. The resulting int to the left of the : is the start position in the list, the int to the right is the end position. So the format is: `list[start:end]`

Answer (score 0):

So then, as far as i can see the loop splits the mids list into chunks the size of chunk and curids is being attribuited those chunks. So for example if mids was a 20 values list and chunk was 4, curids would be attribuited the values mids[0:4],mids[4:8],..mids[16:20] , basically splitting the list in 5